# please tell me the Player using in the McTube App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayer

Can anyone please tell me which player is used in the McTube App?
Because I want to implement the same in my app.
Till now, I am playing in `UIWebView` but as my client suggested the player looks same as in McTube App.

The player looks like this 
[image]

I tried by using `LBYouTubeParser` and `HCYoutubeParser` by using that some videos are not playing.. it is failing to play. I posted the comment for this also, maximum people are facing this problem too. https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser/issues/19#issuecomment-27281247

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to parse YouTube video URL, not what player to use.

The reason why `LBYouTubeParser` & `HCYouTubeParser` aren't playing all videos is because YouTube protects some videos from being extracted by encrypting their signature (clear in VEVO videos).

the encrypted signature is found as `s=....` instead of `sig=...`.

To successfully extract the URL, you have to analyse YouTube code (html & javascript) to discover how they decrypt the signature.

Note that the decryption function changes every now & then, so you have to track their changes.

Some other javascript functions already does that, [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/25105) is one of them, you can check it & do the same :)

Comment: ok thank you.. can you please tell me which player is using McTube App @Muhammad

Comment: I think McTube is using a custom class of `MPMoviePlayerViewController`, the bottom controls are there by default, top controls are customized.

Comment: i think when we use MPMoviePlayerViewController all the youtube videos won't play because of restriction , but in the McTube app all videos are playing with out any disturbance @Muhammad

Comment: It all depends on the URL, if you have the right URL, it will work. BTW, the right URL isn't "www.youtube.com/watch?v=video_id", it is a long URL containing many parameters including itag, signature & your IP address.